# NoReverseMatch in Django?

Tags: python, django, web

I am working on a blog site and I've got an error

NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'about' not found. 'about' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
base.html:

```
   <li><a href="{% url 'blog:about' %}">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.github.com">Github</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com">LinkedIn</a></li>
```

urls.py:

```
app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
]
```

views.py:

```
class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'
```

Comment: this error means django dont know where to send user after user is done with your about page. So, you need to make changes inside your views file according to that. But help you in this i need to see your about template file and also have you created any other template except this one like a home.html or something ?

Comment: Hi ,this is my about.html:
`{% block content %}
    <h1>About This Company :</h1>
    <p>Thonk you for check it out !!!!</p>
{% endblock %}`

Comment: when you click on the about page link does it work ? if not then try this <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>

Comment: also make sure you imported AboutView in urls.py